# Electronic chargers possible solution

Tags: battery-charging

I wonder about using either of these two possible solutions to avoid the problem caused by an internal short between AC input earth and DC output negative within the chargers. In the circuit diagram attached there is a possible diode and two possible internal disconnects marked by 'X's. In case of an internal disconnect any external metal parts can still be earthed without affecting the DC circuit itself.
In the case of a diode, it would be easier but would mean using a diode that can pass whatever earth fault current would be calculated at mains voltage. Plus would the RCD trip with half-wave AC?

My original thread was closed, I don't know if that's normal, as it was only a day old but anyway, I had some unanswered follow-up questions so I will try again: is there a reason that "normal" battery chargers don't have this AC side to DC side connection?
[image: Circuit]

Comment: Your original question was closed because it was about how to use electronic devices correctly. Also, I replied there that modifying the chargers defeats their original safety and functional intention of the output being grounded. Do not modify the chargers, for your own safety. The solution is of course to use two suitable 12v chargers, or single 24V charger intended for two 12V batteries in series. Any two-prong charger should do. You have two maritime-grade safety chargers with three-prong plugs.

Comment: I have not seen your previuous question so it might be a good idea to provide us with some additional context here. However, my advice would be to just use a suitable 24 V charger.

Comment: You need proper equipment or the batteries need to be charged in isolation (common connection between batteries removed). DO NOT MODIFY THOSE BATTERY CHARGERS. You obviously don't understand how this works well enough to to "Mod" or "engineer" the chargers considering you already caused a fire "and couldn't figure out why the breaker didn't trip". Either your going to end up burning your place down or blow the batteries up. Most likely these events will take place when you are not around to control such events.

Comment: I don't understand your answer as to why my orignal question was closed but that's your decision of course, but I learnt from replies to that question that the chargers have an internal short between supply earth and output negative which I didn't know before. A two-pronged charger is not earthed but my question is really about chargers with earths but not an internal earth-negative connection. Mosfet: Do you know why these chargers have a short between earth and negative and others do not ? If you do understand why then why don't you enlighten me rather re-telling me that I don't understand.

Comment: Earth in this context will be the safety ground, so naturally you cannot connect the plus pole of a battery there... this should be self-explanatory. The voltage potential at the left side of your picture is "2 * Vbatt" and in the middle it is "1 * Vbatt", where Vbatt is some voltage higher than the expected ground potential. So if connected where you made an X to the left, at best some RCD would trip, at worst you'll burn something to a crisp. And none of that has anything to do with the AC side.

Comment: Please edit in the context from your previous question, even if it was deleted to make this clearer.

Comment: @Johnh Some chargers have a common earth connections simply cause that was a design decision of the engineer that made the charger. Other chargers don't and are of the floating variety (I have a 4 channel charger that will charge 4 batteries independently because they are galvanically isolated). This means there is no interaction between the charging stages, unlike your set up. There are multiple reasons to tie the bat neg to ground - EMI, compliance, fault triggering, wiring convenience, ect. I don't have a precise reason as I am not the designer nor do I know what products you are using.

Comment: Like @Justme said, Almost any 2-prong charger will work properly for what you are trying to do if you can't find a 2 channel battery charger.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure if the engineer designing this charger had my situation in mind then !  Fault triggering could be important, please elaborate on that if you will, but the other things: EMI, wiring convenience, not important for this machine and if the earth is connected to external metal parts only then it should do it's actual job without problems. Lundin: the original problem arises due to the fact that the mains earth (which comes from the AC supply and makes up 1//3 of a 3-core cable with live and neutral so, AC side) is connected deliberately to the DC negative in this charger.

Comment: I suppose that EMI, wiring convenience have little or nothing to do with electrical safety and will I really put myself/others/the house in great danger if I disconnect a earth-negative connection ?

Comment: **Note to all:** The OP has now stated they do not want to continue with this question. Therefore the question is being closed to indicate that people should not engage with it any further.

Answer (score 1):

If you are unsure and need to ask questions regarding safety, don't touch it. It's done in a certain way for a reason.

Adding a diode to the earth line is a massive safety issue and probably won't solve whatever problem you are reffering to. The diode will be active only for half of the AC cycle. Whatever needs to be earthed in the second supply (after the diode) will not be earthed in any way for 50% of the AC period, and it will be earthed for the other half.

You have a much bigger problem in this system, and that is that you have a short from one supply's positive directly into the other supply's negative, where the supplies share a common ground. If the supplies don't have galvanic isolation, this will disable the whole system at best, burn it down at worst. Removing the earthing won't change this, because the supplies obtain the ground potential from the neutral line, not the earthing line.

You could break the series interconnect to charge in parallel, however this is a potential safety problem waiting to happen (if somebody forgets to disconnect the series line or it fails).

As mentioned by the comments, a much better idea would be to just get a 24V supply and charge in series.

Comment: It's done in a certain way for a reason, fine, OK, but my question is "what is that reason", is it OK to ask that question ? I hope so. Also, please explain this: "if the supplies don't have galvanic isolation this will disable the whole system, burn it down at worst", and this: "the supplies obtain the ground potential from the neutral line".  I agree the AC supply will be connecting the earth to neutral somewhere but what about connecting AC supply earth to DC negative ?

Comment: [1/3] Typically, with mains power, you don't have a guarantee to which line is live and which is neutral. They can be switched around, deliberately or by mistake, and whatever device you have will function in the same way. Also, the neutral line is not neccesarily at 0V respective to earth. That's why there is a separate earth terminal which is normally connected to any metal chassis of a device. As long as this is true, you are not in danger by touching the chassis, because it is shorted to earth potential, and therefore your body's as well (unless you are already touching a live wire).

Comment: [2/4] If both supplies share the same ground without galvanic isolation, then if you connect the positive terminal of one supply to the negative of the other, then it is the same as shorting the positive and negative of the same supply, because the ground is common to both of them - it essentially can be though of the same wire just split in two. In best case, the power supply has short circuit protection and/or this will trip your breaker. Worst case it will cause an overload.

Comment: [3/4] Galvanic isolation means that all potentials at the output are isolated from the input. Think of the output as a battery. You will have some voltage between output + and -, but the voltage between the input and output can be anything. There is no sharing of the ground potential at the output side.

Comment: [4/4] If the supplies don't have galvanic isolation, connecting the DC ground to earth is similar to connecting the AC neutral to earth. Unless these are at exactly the same potential, it will likely trip your RCD, beacuse part of the current from the live wire will simply travel to earth instead of returning to the RCD through neutral. If there is galvanic isolation on the output, then you should be able to connect the DC ground to earth. However keep in mind that if you do this, you are breaking the point of it. You are shorthing the grounds of the supplies and there is no more isolation.

Comment: Here we may have earth and neutral linked somewhere, either by the supplier or at least on the suppliers side of the meter but what i am actually asking is not for an explanation of earthing but where does that come into it with regard to my chargers ? I'm not suggesting getting rid of earthing i'm suggesting removing a link between Supply earth and DC negative.  With regards to galvanic isolation, these chargers have deliberately done away with it, however they don't trip the RCD.

Comment: The real and important question for me is why do I need the electronic chargers to have an internal connection between supply earth and DC output negative?